# ChartJS Bar Issue - Showing "zeros" and not center bars

Tags: javascript, web, charts, chart.js

Im having some trouble with ChartJs and hope you can help. I would like to create a Bar Chart where:

- Zero Lables that only contains dataset with zeros are not showing
- If only one data value in a chart it is cen

I have added the code example here at codepen: [Link to ChartJs CodePen](https://codepen.io/tsgrau/pen/QWyNQwN)

```
var Canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");


var Data1 = {
  label: 'Project A',
  data: [10, 0, 10, 0 ,0 ,0 ,10],
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 99, 132, 0.6)',
  borderWidth: 0,
  yAxisID: "y-axis"
};

var Data2 = {
  label: 'Project B',
  data: [0 , 5, 5, 0 ,0 ,0 ,10],
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 0.6)',
  borderWidth: 0,
  yAxisID: "y-axis"
};

var MonthData = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"],
  datasets: [Data1, Data2]
};

var chartOptions = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      barPercentage: 1,
      categoryPercentage: 0.6
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      id: "y-axis"
    }]
  }
};

var barChart = new Chart(Canvas, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: MonthData,
  options: chartOptions
});
```

Another example, please see below. I have added a link to the source. If i could add data to a Bar Chart the same way it would be perfect.

[image]
[Link to source of picture](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/AutoCalculatedBarWidth/Mvc/Light/)

**EDIT:**
Added a codepen for DX chart: [DX Link](https://codepen.io/tsgrau/pen/PoZNQbw)

/Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChartJS and the DevExtreme chart are 2 different things. If you want the functionality of dxChart in chartJs then you would have to write it yourself (if you don't have access to the source code to see how they did it).

Helping you with the first point is easy - simply unset the data you don't want. Check [here](https://codepen.io/martin-manov/pen/qBbZoWe). Don't forget to remove the label you don't want to show.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= Data1.data.length; i++){
  if (Data1.data[i] === 0 && Data2.data[i] === 0) {
    Data2.data.splice(i, 1);
    Data1.data.splice(i, 1);
    labels.splice(i, 1); // also remove the corresponding label
    i--; // important not to skip any records after removing
  }
}
```

However this sort of data manipulation I would recommend doing in the back end. Just don't set it before sending to the front end and you're done.

For your second point it looks like chartJs cannot help. There is a reason why dxChart is paid and chartJs is free. Learn to make compromises or become a JS ninja. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, i know dxChart is paid, and i have been using the free version for some time. However i better like ChartJS, and based on your feedback it seems like that is a feature missing - hopefully it will get in one day :) For sure a function at the backend in my app.

Comment: The "issue" im facing with ChartJs, is if i have lets say 50 datasets for a single year. i created one with 7 here: https://codepen.io/tsgrau/pen/jOWqJXQ then the plot becomes nearly unreadable.

Comment: I see your point. That would cause user experience issues. That means it's better to rethink what is needed and how to achieve it. If you were to have 50 sets in one month and 1 set in another one your chart would look weird. If that's the case I would suggest going for a line chart and not to remove sets if all of them are zero at the same month. Like I said, chartJS cannot help you with your second point, but I gave you a solution for your first point.

Answer (score 0):

Changing intersect to false for the tooltips should fix the problem. (Intersect: true only shows the tooltips if you're hovering over a datapoint, of which there are none if it's zero)

tooltips configuration can be found here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.6.0/configuration/tooltip.html

```
var chartOptions = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      barPercentage: 1,
      categoryPercentage: 0.6
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      id: "y-axis"
    }]
  },
  tooltips: {
    intersect: false
  }
};
```