# Skip labels when associated value is null in chartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

If I have 12 labels on a chart (one for each month), how can I just show the first 6 if other values are null ?
I use `max: 'Jun'`for the moment but I'd like to automate this: when 'July' changes from null to a value, I'd like the max to become 'Jul'.
Is it possible with ChartJS ?

```
data: {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        datasets: [
            {
                spangaps: true,
                label: 'Exceptionnel',
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null, null, null, null, null, null]
            },
        options: {
               scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                offset: true,
                gridLines: {
                    display: true
                },
                ticks: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    max: 'Jun'
                }
            }]}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62339667/9876136). You can simplify it:

```
var labels = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"];
var data = [5, 6, 4, null, 5, null];
for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
    if (data[i] === null) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
        labels.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

However, if you are sure that once you reach a null value the rest are also null, you can splice not just one but the remaining as well. The trick is to also remove the labels so that no empty data is shown.

PS: I would advise not fetching labels with empty data from your back end if possible.

Comment: It's not working and I don't really know why, I called data from a mongo database, it's not a simple array like in my example. But I'm not sure

Comment: I think it's because I pass values in Handlebars template with a `<script>` and your code can't take these values (your code works well if I create a variable directly in my js file)

Comment: Without knowing what kind of data you're working with we cannot help you. At some point you will have to set it in chartjs the way it is in the example. If you are able to manipulate the data accordingly this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip labels which have null values by checking in the **`callback`** of **`ticks`** like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

        let obj = {
            labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            datasets: [{
                spangaps: true,
                label: 'Exceptionnel',
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null, 5, null, null, null, null]
            }]
        };

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: obj,
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        offset: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true
                        },
                        ticks: {

                            callback: function (value, index, values) {

                                var dataValue = obj.datasets[0].data;

                                if (dataValue[index]) {
                                    return values[index];
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

If you would like to remove spaces which are null in values and don't want to show this then use this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

        let obj = {
            labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            datasets: [{
                spangaps: true,
                label: 'Exceptionnel',
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null, 5, null, null, null, 3]
            }]
        };

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: obj,
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        offset: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

        var len = obj.datasets[0].data.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len;) {

            if (obj.datasets[0].data[i] === null) {
                obj.datasets[0].data.splice(i, 1);
                obj.labels.splice(i, 1);
            } else if (obj.datasets[0].data.length < 2) {
                break;
            } else {
                i++;
            }

        }

        myChart.update();


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! But now I have a white space. How can I expand the chart to fill the entire space ?

Comment: Would you like to remove that area as well which are null?

Comment: As long as the value is null yes

Comment: Any idea ? I tried the solution above but I don't know how to remove white spaces left by null values. With `max` in ticks' option ?

Comment: One thing you can do that remove the null values with their label and update your chart again. That's the way you can remove the white spaces which have null values.

Comment: @If_celine, in your case I think my second given answer will work for you. Let me know if it's working or not?

Comment: The question is answered but my problem isn't solved because I use handlebars to fetch data. So my `data:` can be a `coteEu` variable that looks like this: `var coteEu = [{{{ cote_annual_jan_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_feb_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_mar_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_apr_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_may_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_jun_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_jul_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_aug_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_sep_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_oct_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_nov_base_eu }}}, {{{ cote_annual_dec_base_eu }}}]; in a `<script> in HTML

Comment: The error is with `null`, I haven't got any null values but undefined or empty ones. How to change this ?

Comment: Just change the condition like this `if(!obj.datasets[0].data[i])`.

Comment: I tried already but the page is loading indefinitely in this case. Without `!` it's not but the labels are inverted

Comment: Ok got it. Change like this `if (isNaN(obj.datasets[0].data[i]) || obj.datasets[0].data[i] === 0 || obj.datasets[0].data[i] === false || obj.datasets[0].data[i] === "" || obj.datasets[0].data[i] === undefined || obj.datasets[0].data[i] === null)`. Just remove any condition that doesn't need in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but the problem is th same...

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The page loads undefinitly and I don't know why

Comment: Just give me 5 mins, I will fix this out.

Comment: It was because of `for (var i = 0; i < len;)`, I changed it with `for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)`, it's better but there are month without values.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove tailing `null` entries from your `data`, you can proceed as follows. The [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method removes the last element from an array.

```
while(data[data.length-1] == null) { 
  data.pop(); // remove tailing null 
  labels.pop(); // remove corresponding label
}
```

> The important thing is to always also remove the corresponding entry from `labels`, each time you remove an entry from `data`.

In case you also wanted to remove leading `null` entries from your `data`, this can be done as follows. The [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) method removes the first element from an array.

```
while(data[0] == null) {
  data.shift(); // remove leading null  
  labels.shift(); // remove corresponding label
}
```

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
const labels = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null, 5, null, null, null, null];

while(data[0] == null) {
  data.shift(); // remove leading null  
  labels.shift(); // remove corresponding label
}

while(data[data.length-1] == null) { 
  data.pop(); // remove tailing null 
  labels.pop(); // remove corresponding label
}

var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Exceptionnel',
      data: data
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        offset: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```