# Remove white space in ChartJS when value is null

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My question is an extension of a previous one ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791870/skip-labels-when-associated-value-is-null-in-chartjs/62792769?noredirect=1#comment111043388_62792769)).

I remove the labels with null associated datas but now I'd like to remove space when this is the case (I have white spaces ath the left in this example).

Have I to deal with `min` and `max` ticks options?

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    let obj = {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        datasets: [{
            spangaps: true,
            label: 'Exceptionnel',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null, 5, null, null, null, null]
        }]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: obj,
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    offset: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: true
                    },
                    ticks: {

                        callback: function (value, index, values) {

                            var dataValue = obj.datasets[0].data;

                            if (dataValue[index]) {
                                return values[index];
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Why not continue the discussion in your previous questions since the answer you used is still not correct. Check [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62795263/9876136)

Comment: Because it seems to be another question because I didn't mention the fact that I wanted to remove white spaces

Comment: @lf_celine, have you already solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you consider a whites space at the left of your example is actually an invisible bar of value 1. This can be solved by defining option `yAxes.ticks.beginAtZero: true` or alternatively also `yAxes.ticks.min: 0`.

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true
  }
}],
```

In case you want to remove leading `null` entries from your `data`, this can be done as follows. The [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) method removes the first element from an array.

```
while(data[0] == null) {
  data.shift(); // remove leading null  
  labels.shift(); // remove corresponding label
}
```

To also remove the tailing `null` entries from your `data`, you can proceed as follows. The [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method removes the last element from an array.

```
while(data[data.length-1] == null) { 
  data.pop(); // remove tailing null 
  labels.pop(); // remove corresponding label
}
```

> The important thing is to always also remove the corresponding entry from `labels`, each time you remove an entry from `data`.

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
const labels = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null, 5, null, null, null, null];

while(data[0] == null) {
  data.shift(); // remove leading null  
  labels.shift(); // remove corresponding label
}

while(data[data.length-1] == null) { 
  data.pop(); // remove tailing null 
  labels.pop(); // remove corresponding label
}

var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Exceptionnel',
      data: data
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        offset: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```